# Check if next char in a string is a space

Tags: android, space

I would like to check if the current char is a blank space as i dont want to change that. So i would like to change all the letters like i do now, but keep the spaces.

e.g. "that man" with C = 2 should become "vjcv ocp".

thanks in advance :)

```
    String initialString = yourString.getText().toString();
        char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++) {
            C = Integer.valueOf(ceasarNr);

            chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) + C)%29);
        }
        String resultString = new String(chars);
        krypteredeTekst.setText(resultString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the iteration if the character is a space:

```
String initialString = yourString.getText().toString();
    char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++) {
        //Skip if it is space.
        if chars[i-1] == ' ';
             continue;

        C = Integer.valueOf(ceasarNr);

        chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) + C)%29);
    }
    String resultString = new String(chars);
    krypteredeTekst.setText(resultString);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much :) didnt know i could do like that. Am still new at programming you see ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is method for checking if char is blank space ->

```
    String initialString = yourString.getText().toString();
    char[] chars = initialString.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 1; i <= chars.length; i++) {
        C = Integer.valueOf(ceasarNr);

        if(!Character.isWhitespace(chars.charAt(i-1)) {
            chars[i-1] = characters.get((characters.indexOf(chars[i-1]) + C)%29);
        }
    }
    String resultString = new String(chars);
    krypteredeTekst.setText(resultString);
```